# Wordpress RSS feed coming as blank

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, rss

I have created a wordpress site. I am using wordpress version 3.9.1 installed on my local Ubuntu 14.04 machine. However, when I am trying to access the RSS feed from the URL  `http:/localhost/feed`  the page is coming as blank. I have not added any 'posts' on my site. Instead I have around 100 'pages'. I have enable permalinks as well. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: I like your question so 1 up vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to show your pages in feed(`http:/localhost/feed`) than add the below code in your functions.php of theme.

```
add_filter('request', 'feed_request');
function feed_request($qv){
   $rss_post_types = array('post', 'page');
    if(isset($qv['feed']) && !isset($qv['post_type']))
      $qv['post_type'] = $rss_post_types;
    return $qv;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. This has solved my problem. I have one more query. If i change the theme, doesn't that mean I have to add this in the new theme's function.php as well ? Is there any way I can make this generic and applicable for all themes ?

Comment: most easiest way to convert it into plugin and activate it otherwise you have to copy this into all your themes.